# Ruby version issues

Tags: centos, version, ruby, gem

I have been practising setting up a production environment with puppet, and now I'm setting up everything to accommodate HTTP requests with Apache.

Since Puppet runs on Ruby, I also need Passenger to get it running, but I can't install it because I keep getting an error saying that I need a fresher version of Ruby installed. 
At first this was an actual issue because I'm using a core version of CentOS 6.5 that only comes with Ruby 1.8.

I then updated the yum repos, the system itself and did `wget` to download the current version, configured and installed which gets me to where I stand right now. I installed Gems and tried to get Passenger again but I am faced with the same wall, version problems. 
Here you can see the installed version of ruby and the issue.

```
[vagrant@puppetmaster ~]$ sudo gem install rack passenger
ERROR:  Error installing rack:
        rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
ERROR:  Error installing passenger:
        rake requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
[vagrant@puppetmaster ~]$ ruby --version
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: Have you googled for it? I have found several results with a similar issue.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086)  I have transcribed the contents for you, but you may want to check for errors in transcription.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a couple of hours of searching and a lot of failed solutions on Google I finally found something that did actually work. The following commands actually solved it.

```
sudo gem install rack -v 1.6.0
sudo gem install rake -v 10.4.2
sudo gem install passenger -v 4.0.56
```

Apparently it's what everyone else was saying about source issues, just their solutions were not working in my case.

Comment: You can accept your own answer to let others know that the problem has been solved